Help undeleting Data - Mount Android card on PC
I need a way to recover deleted data. To see if I can recover some WhatsApp history that the device has sent to limbo.
I tried some tools, but to no avail. I was expecting to be able to mount the drive as an external drive, mount it on Windows/Linux, and then run the usual tools.
Any ideas on how can I achieve that?
The device is a Xiaomi phone, and I can try to root if needed.
[Edit/More context]
The problem happened when it was time to switch to a new device. History was not brought to the new one, it kept failing. But it was ok in the old one.
It is not my device. I am trying to help a friend. I suggested the friend delete some chats/images. While they were doing that, all history was gone.
The same was happening with the spouse's friend device too. But deleting the whole backup and doing the process again did the trick.
But for the friend, everything is wiped. I was hoping to get some of old .crypt and key files to restore at least something.
Thank you!

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to decrypt msgstore.db.crypt8 file

Whatsapp data is encrypted, so it is unlikely that you can recover it with any tools.  However, Whatsapp is backed up to the cloud.  As long as you haven't stopped the backup from happening, you may be able to recover the history.  Try logging on, on a different phone and see if it comes back.  Or ask your friend to send it back to you.
